Im not able to access my web client secret in firebase
im using auth.js for authentication system using google but im not able to access web client secret. It just shows me the placeholder I even controlled from inspect this page. Why im not able to get the secret, how can I fix this?

I tried to access but I couldn't.

Same here. Even checking the HTML code it seems the secret value is no longer present, so it looks like it's not (or no longer) possible to copy this secret from within the Firebase console itself.
However, when I hover over the ? it shows this:


Update this if you want to reuse a web client ID from an existing Google project. You can find your web client ID and secret by selecting your project and OAuth 2.0 client from the Google API Console

I still don't see the secret for my OAuth 2 clients in the Google API Console either, but hopefully it will show for yours. If not, the secret may only be available when you initially create the OAuth 2 client.
Either way, it's probably a good idea to reach out to Firebase support - as that Web-client secret input is quite useless in its current state.

ahh okay i understand im sorry for my carelessness

If you change the web client id to a different one (e.g. from w different project), the field becomes accessible. It's an input field.
You can check your secret in the GCP console in Apis & Services -> Credentials -> Web client (auto created by Google Service)

Click the (?) icon next to Web SDK Configuration, then click Google API Console.
Under OAuth 2.0 Client IDs, click the download button, it should have the Client secret there.

